Unexpected value 'condition'
I am trying to resolve my config issue with Azure DevOps Pipeline. I am using templates in my main pipeline, but there some cases that the next pipeline should work only if previous one was passed. That previous template passed result is based on the output from the log.
Short version of my pipeline:
   - deployment: Development
     <cutting off the rest of the code>
                - checkout: APP
                - script: |
                    ansible-playbook \
                      playbooks/installation.yml
                - template: templates/app_log.yml@Pipelines
                  parameters:
                    ssh: $(Endpoint)
                    port: $(Port)
                - template: templates/app_symlink.yml@Pipelines
                  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['appLog.status'], 'Succeeded'))
                  parameters:
                    ssh: $(Endpoint)
                    port: $(Port)

templates/app_app.yml
parameters:
  - name: ssh
    type: string
    displayName: 'SSH'
  - name: port
    type: string
    displayName: 'Port'
  - name: name
    type: string
    default: 'appLog'
<cutting off the rest of the code>

When the app_log.yml finishing its job by checking the status of all tests it shows All tests passed which should be treat as trigger to create a symlink to the new version of app by path, however with my attempts of creating some if before the -template or as I showed in the above code it leads to the error each time (now it shows the error like in the title). On the other hand, even if one test failed it shouldn't create any symlink.

You cannot set conditions when using templates, so the following is invalid:
- template: templates/app_symlink.yml@Pipelines
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['appLog.status'], 'Succeeded'))
  parameters:
    # ...

The workaround is to add a condition parameter to the templates/app_symlink.yml template - example:
# templates/app_symlink.yml

parameters:
  - name: condition
    type: string
    displayName: 'Condition'
    default: ''

  # other parameters here

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Hello world"
    displayName: 'Hello world'
    ${{ if ne(parameters.condition, '') }}:
      condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}

You'll have to do the same thing to all steps in the template that depend on the condition.
Using the template:
- template: templates/app_symlink.yml@Pipelines
  parameters:
    # ...
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['appLog.status'], 'Succeeded'))
    # ...

Consider adding other parameters to your jobs/steps templates as well, in order to make them configurable and extensible such as timeoutInMinutes, retryCountOnTaskFailure, etc.

It works, but dont understand where is the eq(variables['appLog.status'] defined? I read several article from you GitHub repo, very informative. I think I need to follow some of your recommendations.

@scrapkowe I have no idea either, I just copied the condition from your code sample :-) It's impossible for me to know where that variable is coming from. If this answer fixes your issue please consider accepting it.

@scrapkowe the first place where I'd search for the variable is templates/app_log.yml@Pipelines

Ok, works again, thank you, just last question. I see that in your GitHub you recommend use variables.yml, and I try to use for some variables the variables group from Azure UI directly, is that any reason why didn't mention about that in your blog?

@scrapkowe not sure if I understand your question, what exact guideline(s) are you talking about?

@scrapkowe I do recommend declaring variables in templates, including variable groups.
You can use the group: myvariablegroup syntax to reference a variable group in a template.
See example in DO: Store Sensitive Information in Variable Groups.

Yes, your guidelines from GitHub which I started reading. Short and informative.
